# Copy directories containing certain string

Tags: python, directory, copy

I am trying to copy folders containing a certain string in their filename ('Baseline') from one drive to another with python on windows.

My folder structure is as follows:

```
Data
|patient01
||001_Baseline_CT
|||dicom1.dicom
|||dicom2.dicom
|||dicom3.dicom
|||...
||001_Recurrence_CT
|patient02
||002_Baseline_CT
|||dicom1.dicom
|||dicom2.dicom
|||dicom3.dicom
|||...
```

I would like to copy all folders incl. their content that have the string "Baseline", to create a new directory looking like this:

```
|Output_directory
||001_Baseline_CT
|||dicom1.dicom
|||dicom2.dicom
|||dicom3.dicom
|||...
||002_Baseline_CT
|||dicom1.dicom
|||dicom2.dicom
|||dicom3.dicom
|||...
```

I tried the following script, but it doesn't work (I'm very new to python, forgive me for the messy code):

```
import shutil
import os


input_dir = input('/path/to_copy')
output_dir = input('path/to_receive/')


for file in os.walk(input_dir):
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, '*Baseline*'):
        if not os.path.exists(output_dir):
            os.makedirs(output_dir)

    shutil.copy2(os.path.join(input_dir, file), os.path.join(output_dir, file))
```

Does anyone have a solution to copy folders based on a specific string?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

**strong text**You can use [`fnmatch.filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fnmatch.html#filter.html) to select basenames and [`shutil.copytree`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#copytree) to copy a directory and its content.

Notice that by default `copytree` will automatically create a directory given a string path and throw an error if such string describe an existing path. But by passing the `dirs_exist_ok` parameter this behavior can be bypassed and the content of the directory will be *overwritten*.

Assumed from the diagram in the question that "Baseline"s directories are in the **second level**

```
import os
import fnmatch
import shutil

input_dir =  # path1
output_dir = # path2

pattern = '*Baseline*'

# auxiliary function
def filter_by_dir(path):
    return filter(os.path.isdir, (os.path.join(path, basename) for basename in os.listdir(path)))

# check if destination directory exist
is_out_dir = os.path.isdir(output_dir)

# loops over directories
for sub_dir in filter_by_dir(input_dir):
    for pattern_dir in fnmatch.filter(filter_by_dir(sub_dir), pattern):
        shutil.copytree(pattern_dir, output_dir, dirs_exist_ok=is_out_dir)
```

---

If the directories to be matched are **directly** contained in `input_dir`, so 1 level deep, then the `for`-loop should be like this instead:

```
#...

# loops over directories
for pattern_dir in fnmatch.filter(filter_by_dir(input_dir), pattern):
    shutil.copytree(pattern_dir, output_dir, dirs_exist_ok=is_out_dir)
```

Comment: I tried it out, but get stuck at the final line with this error:     shutil.copytree(os.path.join(sub_dir, baseline_dir), output_dir, dirs_exist_ok=is_out_dir)
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Thank so much for your efforts, while I don't get an error message anymore, the output directory remains empty, so it still doesn't copy the files I'm afraid.

Comment: Found the problem and fixed it. The cause was that `listdir` returns the basename and and the filtering was not done with the right paths